# Not Showing Browsable Api interface in djanog rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

not showing browsable api interface in django rest_framework 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api
here is my code

> auth_app/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager,PermissionsMixin

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,password=None,**extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email Field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,**extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_superuser(self,email,password=None,**extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',True)
        return self.create_user(email,password,**extra_fields)
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

> auth_app/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id','email','first_name','last_name','is_active','is_staff')
```

> auth_app/views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics,permissions,status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from .serializers import CustomUserSerializer

class RegistrationAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self,request):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            return Response(
                {
                    "refresh": str(refresh),
                    "access": str(refresh.access_token),
                },
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
            )
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
 
   
class LoginAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self,request):
        email = request.data.get("email")
        password = request.data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(request, email=email,password=password)
        if user:
            login(request,user)
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            return Response(
                {
                    "refresh":str(refresh),
                    "access": str(refresh.access_token),
                },
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK
            )
        return Response({"error":"Invalid Credentials"},status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
@method_decorator(login_required,name="dispatch")      
class LogoutAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self,request):
        logout(request)
        return Response({"message":"Logged out Successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

> auth_app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import RegistrationAPIView,LoginAPIView,LogoutAPIView

urlpatterns=[
    path('register/',RegistrationAPIView.as_view,name="register"),
    path('login/',LoginAPIView.as_view,name='login'),
    path('logout/',LogoutAPIView.as_view,name='logout'),
]
```

> auth_project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/',include('auth_app.urls')),
    ]
```

Please someone help to resolve this issue unable to find where is the problem i am trying to build authentication api with django rest_framework and then consume it with react but i am facing that broblem and unable to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'rest_framework' to INSTALLED_APPS under settings.py file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...,
   'rest_framework',
   ...,
]
```

If you already have done that. You might have changed the renderer setting. For BrowsableAPI to be displayed you need to keep BrowsableAPIRenderer under DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES in project settings.

Django Rest Framework comes with following default renderers:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
}
```

Comment: i changed as_view to this as_view()

`from django.urls import path
from .views import RegistrationAPIView,LoginAPIView,LogoutAPIView

urlpatterns=[
    path('register/',RegistrationAPIView.as_view(),name="register"),
    path('login/',LoginAPIView.as_view(),name='login'),
    path('logout/',LogoutAPIView.as_view(),name='logout'),
]`
know

`api/register
api/login`
thats are showing browsable interface but still why i am not getting browsable interface at

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77270486/not-getting-browsable-interface-at-http-127-0-0-18000-api